# Execute Clojure block (or selection) doesn't work in Atom proto-repl

Tags: clojure, atom-editor, proto-repl

I've installed a fresh version of Atom 1.9.9 on Windows and set it up as described in [Atom Clojure Setup](https://gist.github.com/jasongilman/d1f70507bed021b48625).

When trying to execute a block of code in REPL, as per this explanation in its startup:

> ctrl-alt-, then b Execute block. Finds the block of Clojure code your
>   cursor is in and executes that.
>
> ctrl-alt-, s Executes the selection. Sends the selected text to the
>   REPL.

no execution happens, instead the cursor just moves backwards.

Atom key binding resolver seems to link this key combination to the atom-text-editor emacs.json behavior, however this behavior is not mentioned in the above setup guide.

[image]

Also, the key bindings are not showing for the **proto-repl** package in the menu, my understanding is that they should as they do for other Atom packages:

[image]

Are these normal deficiencies with **Atom proto-repl** package on Windows or am I missing some important additional setting?

Answer (score 3):

If it's not executing the Proto REPL command it's likely that the key binding is already used by another set of keys. Atom has a great tool for investigating key binding problems called the key binding resolver. Can you enable the keybinding resolver and see what's triggered with the keybinding. Keybindings can be a pain because of conflicts among many packages.

Keybindings can be customized too. See the keybindings in the Proto REPL repo https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl/blob/master/keymaps/proto-repl.cson these can be added to your own keybinding file with changes that avoid conflicts with other packages you use.

You can also ask questions on Proto REPL in the Clojure slack channel #protorepl.

Comment: Had the same problem. What did it for me was adding the general proto-repl keybindings from your link in my keymap.cson